# Use PHP class between 2 subdomains

Tags: php, class, subdomain

I have a PHP class on a subdomain I want to use in another subdomain. I can include it on the second subdomain but when I call the class, I have a "class not found" error.

On subdomain A (http://a.mydomain.com), file: MyClass.php:

```
class MyClass {
  public function getTest() {
    return 'Hello World !';
  }
}
```

On subdomain B (http://d.mydomain.com):

```
include 'http://a.mydomain.com/MyClass.php';

$class = new MyClass();
echo $class->getTest();
```

Error displayed:
Fatal error: *Class 'myClass' not found in /var/www/subdomainb/index.php on line 3*

Anyone has an idee to do that ?

Comment: You don't want to include using a web URL. You want to use an absolute path

Comment: Are both subdomains on same server? If yes, you can specify a relative/absolute path.

Comment: It's probably a stupid idea, but you can also try and download the file to your subdomain B and then include it using relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include files using their paths not URLs. I am not sure about your file structure but it is about like this:

```
include '/var/www/subdomaina/MyClass.php';
```

Also consider using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Answer (score 0):

See these questions:

- [Secure way of remote PHP include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172637/secure-way-of-remote-php-include)
- [including a remote file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php)
- [Should I include locally or remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714397/should-i-include-locally-or-remotely)

There are quite many answers to your question on StackOverflow.

It boils down to: *Never* `include` files from remote servers.